# Can I include a variable in an `sh` command in zeppelin?

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin with Hadoop on a Spark cluster.

I'd like to run a command to check files on s3 and I'd like to use a variable.

This is my code

```
%sh

aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/my_folder/
```

Can I replace `my-bucket/my_folder/` with a variable?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "a variable"? A Python variable? If so, I'm not sure. But if you just want to pull the path out onto another line, you can use a shell variable:

```
%sh

export AWS_FOLDER=my-bucket/my_folder/
aws s3 ls s3://$AWS_FOLDER
```